# Creating a directory in hdfs path

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

When I try to create `dir` in `hdfs` for writing data in cluster using the command:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /dir name
```

It does not create and shows the following message in centos:

> mkdir: /dir name: input/output

Can anyone help with this query ?

Answer (score 0):

Your command is the same as this

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /dir "/home/$(whoami)/name"
```

Both should work, assuming you have permissions to write to the HDFS root for `/dir`